# Optimal way to manage multiple HTMLs with the same code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, web

I am building my own photography website where dynamic content is the pictures.

Right now, I have seperate HTML files for each page, which is very inefficient when I make any code changes.

I tried javascript to handle the dynamic content, but back and forward navigation doesn't work. I am not sure if php is appropriate as it's server side scripting.

What would be an optimal way to update the dynamic content?

Comment: Try looking into AJAX

Comment: There are a million ways to do what you want. The best depends on what you're comfortable with if you're doing it yourself, otherwise, it depends on who you're going to pay to do it for you. You don't need anything server-side unless you're trying to capture data. Many template systems or frameworks for building single-page javascript applications will help you make sure the back button works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. It seems that you are simply duplicating each dynamic page to create a static HTML file.

Of course you should stop ASAP this, and you should use a proper framework to manage your dynamic content. Since you have mentioned PHP I suggest you to take a look at [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)

You could create a route like:

```
yoursite.com/image/id-image
```

That can be managed by Laravel by:

```
Route::get('image/{id}', function($id) {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need it's some sort of templating engine, if you have experience with javascript [jade](http://jade-lang.com) would be a good option for you.